# parent ul color in the background of dropdown child li

Tags: html, css

In this code (practicing css dropdown menu) the background color of the main parent ul is Red, and background color of the dropdown child li "Sub" is violet. Now when I tried to move the dropdown child li "Sub" 20px right from its position, I see the background color Red still appearing. You can see this if you hover your mouse over li "Hello" I dont want that. It's like something shifting from its placeholder leaving behind the original placeholder color. I want no background color if I shift the dropdown child li "Sub" from its original position to either left/right/up/down

```css
html body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.roundborder {
 border-radius:5px
}

.container {
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 width: auto;
 background-color: rgba(153,204,0,1);
 height: 25px;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 /* [disabled]top: 0px; */
}

ul {
 text-align: center;
 /* [disabled]border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1); */
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-left: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 /* [disabled]border: 1px solid black; */
 /* [disabled]padding: 5px; */
 height: 25px;
 width: 40px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-left: 30px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}

ul > li > ul {
 padding-left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1); */
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 border-style: none;
}

ul > li > ul > li {
 display: block;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 40px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,102,1);
 left: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(204,102,153,1);
}

ul li:hover > ul {
 visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="roundborder">
<li>Hello
<ul> 
<li>Sub</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Cool</li>
<li>World</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `ul > li > ul{` to have `background:transparent;` because it is currently getting `background:red;` from `ul{`

```css
html body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.roundborder {
 border-radius:5px
}

.container {
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 width: auto;
 background-color: rgba(153,204,0,1);
 height: 25px;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 /* [disabled]top: 0px; */
}

ul {
 text-align: center;
 /* [disabled]border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1); */
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-left: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 /* [disabled]border: 1px solid black; */
 /* [disabled]padding: 5px; */
 height: 25px;
 width: 40px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-left: 30px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}

ul > li > ul {
 padding-left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1); */
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 border-style: none;
    background:transparent;
}

ul > li > ul > li {
 display: block;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 40px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,102,1);
 left: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(204,102,153,1);
}

ul li:hover > ul {
 visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="roundborder">
<li>Hello
<ul> 
<li>Sub</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Cool</li>
<li>World</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Top tip: using the 'computed styles' in your browsers inspector will show you what values your element is getting and where it is getting them from for easy debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's because you had `left:20px;` so when it was hovering it was adding the 20px; which included the red background.

```css
html body {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
}

.roundborder {
 border-radius:5px
}

.container {
 margin-top: 5%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 10%;
 width: auto;
 background-color: rgba(153,204,0,1);
 height: 25px;
 position: relative;
 left: 0px;
 /* [disabled]top: 0px; */
}

ul {
 text-align: center;
 /* [disabled]border: thin solid rgba(0,0,0,1); */
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0%;
 padding-top: 0;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-left: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
}

li {
 display: inline-block;
 /* [disabled]border: 1px solid black; */
 /* [disabled]padding: 5px; */
 height: 25px;
 width: 40px;
 margin-top: auto;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-bottom: auto;
 margin-left: 30px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}

ul > li > ul {
 padding-left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1); */
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 border-style: none;
}

ul > li > ul > li {
 display: block;
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 40px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,102,1);
 background-color: rgba(204,102,153,1);
}

ul li:hover > ul {
 visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul class="roundborder">
<li>Hello
<ul> 
<li>Sub</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li>Cool</li>
<li>World</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe he wants it to be `left:20px` but he doesn't want the red to be there when it is `left:20px;`

Comment: Okay my minsunderstanding. I see you've found a solution though:)